# Generate a multi-category axis label on al Chart

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to generate multi-category chart axis in excel with VBA. (see example picture below)

My attempt at doing this with VBA, normaly i submit an array for my xvalues and this time I am trying to submit two arrays but I get type mismatch. Any ideas on how to pull this off?

```
With chart.SeriesCollection(1)
    .Name = "Data1"
    .Values = avgValue1
    .XValues = Array(columnVAlue, labelValue)
```

[image: Pick with multiple category axis]

*** UPDATE ***

I am using this chart from within Access so I cannot interface with a worksheet.

Comment: Edited the question to focus the answers a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The image you post comes from a [blog post](http://peltiertech.com/chart-with-a-dual-category-axis/) by Excel charting guru Jon Peltier. In the comments of that post Jon points out a few times that a multi level axis can only be passed in from a worksheet range, not from an array.

> I don’t know about charting in Access. But in Excel, you can’t pass an array as a delimited string and have the dual axis come out right. You need to use a worksheet range.

and

> As I stated in my previous comment, it is not possible to pass anything other than a worksheet range that will produce a category axis with categories and subcategories. You cannot pass a string that will do this, nor can you pass a 2D array. At least I haven’t been clever enough to find a way.

So, if you use VBA to construct the chart, write the two arrays into two columns of a worksheet, then use that range for the X axis category. You can use a hidden sheet if you don't want the chart prep to upset your workbook look and feel.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately I cannot move forward with what you propose. I am using this chart as an embedded object in an Access form so it must be entirely driven by VBA which prompted me posting this question to the larger audience of StackOverflow. Thanks for the attempt!

Comment: In this case, the answer is "It can't be done". Jon Peltier makes Excel charts sit up and beg. If he has not found a way to do it, then there most likely is not one to do what you want to do.

Comment: I've recently revisited this, and I've tried a lot of different permutations of arrays in VBA. Nothing I've encountered gives these nice tiered axis ticks and labels.